# preg_replace with unicode

Tags: php, regex, unicode, preg-replace

I'm using the following regular expression with `preg_replace` to strip the string of any punctuation:

```
$string = preg_replace("#((?!-|')\pP)+#", '', $string);
```

But I realized that it ruins some unicode characters. When the string is something like this `"höpöttää?!..."`, I get back this `"h�p�ttää"` with no punctuation but ruined characters.

I read the PHP documentation and found some advice to use `...`u modifier. So I tried this:

```
$string = preg_replace("`#((?!-|')\pP)+#`u", '', $string);
```

And it really fixed the problem with characters. But now it stopped removing the punctuation. With this string `"höpöttää?!..."`, I get the same `"höpöttää?!..."`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know what backticks doing there.

```
$string = preg_replace("#(?![-'])\pP#u", '', $string);
```

or

```
$string = preg_replace("#[^-'\PP]#u", '', $string);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qA2qM7/1)